# I want to my web be able manipulate a file from my hard disk. What should I do?

Tags: web, frontend, backend

I am a beginner and I create a web app with react, I want to my web app be able to read and write a json or csv from my hard disk, I've done this easy with c++ and python 
 I should learn about node.js, django or something like that? I've search and I don't know what to do

What should I do?
Edit: In this question I mean my disk no matter what, I readed the answers and already know what this is not a good idea

Comment: "from my hard disk" - do you mean the server's hard disk or the user's hard disk? Or do you mean *your* disk no matter what? Please clarify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the beauty of the web is that web browsers generally do not have access to the computer's filesystem. This is an intentional security choice. It would be horrible if advertisers could see the contents of your hard drive.

There are technologies that let individual websites store information on your computer that act a little bit like a filesystem, ranging from old school cookies to more advanced databases like LocalStorage or IndexedDB.